# Regular expression needs an extra whitespace at the end

Tags: c, regex

Consider this code:

```
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char **ret = NULL, **t;
    char *buffer;
    pcre *re;
    const char *error;
    int erroffset, rc = 1, arraylength = 0, ovector[2], i = 0;

    const char *string = "WORD";
    buffer = malloc(strlen(string)+1);

    re = pcre_compile("[A-Za-z0-9]+|\\\"[A-Za-z0-9\\s\\.'\\?]+\\\"", PCRE_MULTILINE,  &error,  &erroffset,  NULL);
    if (re == NULL ) printf ("pcre_compile error: %s\n", error);

    while (rc > 0) {
        rc = pcre_exec(re, NULL, string, strlen(string),  i,  0,  ovector, 2);
        bzero(buffer, strlen(string));
        pcre_copy_substring(string, ovector, rc, 0, buffer, strlen(string));

        if (rc > 0) {
            printf("BUFFER: %s\n", buffer);
        }
        i = ovector[1];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
[bart@localhost tests]$ ./pcre 
BUFFER:
```

I expect to get `WORD`. When I added a whitespace character after `WORD`:

```
const char *string = "WORD ";
```

it does work:

```
[bart@localhost tests]$ ./pcre 
BUFFER: WORD
```

Also, when I add more words, it works.

I tried to test my regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/), and it tells me it should work without the whitespace character.

What am I missing here?

**Update** When I change my regex to `[A-Za-z0-9]+` it still doesn't work without the whitespace.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the pcre library and not [POSIX regular expressions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) (`<regex.h>`)?

Comment: @NominalAnimal probably. I started this code base in 2003, so there might be a reason. Perhaps I can port it to posix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `pcre_copy_substring`, the buffer was too small. This:

```
pcre_copy_substring(string, ovector, rc, 0, buffer, strlen(string)+1);
```

fixed it.

Comment: How about removing `1` here `buffer = malloc(strlen(string)+1);`?

Comment: Note that if you had checked the return value from [`pcre_copy_substring()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcre_copy_substring.3.html), you would have known immediately that the trouble was insufficient memory.  Functions have return codes for a good reason — check them, especially if something is going wrong.  Actually, you need to check the return codes even when things aren't going wrong because you don't know when a change somewhere in your code will make things go wrong.